# Fast search and delete in a std::list of objects

Tags: c++, list, stdlist

I have a very large list of objects (nodes), and I want to be able to remove/delete elements of the list based on a set of values inside of them. 
Preferably in constant time...

The objects (among other things) has values like:

```
long long int nodeID;
int depth;
int numberOfClusters;
double [] points;
double [][] clusters;
```

What I need to do is to look through the list, and check if there are any elements that has the same values in all fields except for `nodeID`.

Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
for(i = nodes.begin(); i != nodes.end(); i++)
{
    for(j = nodes.begin(); j != nodes.end(); j++)
    {
        if(i != j)
        {
            if(compareNodes((*i), (*j)))
            {
                j = nodes.erase (j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `compareNodes()` compares the values inside the two nodes. But this is wildly inefficient.

I'm using `erase`because that seems to be the only way to delete an element in the middle of a `std::list`.

Optimally, I would like to be able to find an element based on these values, and remove it from the list if it exists.

I am thinking some sort of hash map to find the element (a pointer to the element) in constant time, but even if I can do that, I can't find a way to remove the element without iterating through the list. 
It seemes that I have to use `erase` , but that requires iterating through the list, which means linear complexity in the list size. 
There is also `remove_if` but again, same problem linear complexity in list size.

Is there no way to get remove an element from a `std::list` without iterating through the whole list?

Comment: 0. Ok, thats a good point, that will of course help a little. 1. Will an iterator always point to the same element, even if the list is changed? If so, then I think that will help me immensely!

Comment: Why do you think `erase` will require iterating through the entire list? `std::list` is a doubly linked list therefore [`erase` is a constant time operation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase)

Comment: Be aware: erasing an element will invalidate your iterators!

Comment: @StefanoBuora not necessarily for a `std::list` the only problem I see in the way they are doing it is that they are likely to skip over a node, `erase` returns the element after the one erased which `j` is set to and then `j` is incremented again at the end of the loop.

Comment: Is it possible to sort your list or the order must be preserved? If the sort is viable you can sort and then check that every "next" element is different from his previuos. In that way you can avoid iterators invalidation and obtain a complexity of O(NlogN) <sort> + O(N) <search for duplicates> so a final one of O(NlogN)

Comment: sjdowling: Because erase is performed on an iterator, and to get the iterator to point to the element, one must iterate until the iterator points to the correct element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you can speed up your existing solution by starting `j` at `std::next(i)` instead of `nodes.begin()` (assuming your `compareNodes` function is commutative).

Second, the hashmap approach sounds viable. But why keep a pointer to the element as a value in the map, when you can keep an iterator? They're both "a thing which references the element," but you can use the iterator to erase the element. And `std::list` iterators don't invalidate when the list is modified (they're most probably just pointers under the hood).

Thirdly, if you want to encapsulate/automate the lookup & sequential access, you can look into [Boost.Multi-index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) to build a container with both sequential and hashed access.

Comment: Wow - just using next(i) cut time in half! Thank you for that tip!
The iterator keeps a pointer to the element before and after the iterator, right? Does that not mean that erasing the element just before the iterator (from another function for example) invalidates the iterator?

Comment: @user3162941 That would violate what the standard requires. The iterator (most likely) keeps a pointer to the node of the `list`. That node contains the next & previous pointers, and the payload.